# Why the image attribute doesn't have method filename to upload to gcs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload an image to gcs using python flask. I have referred to the documentation provided by the google,https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage, but I am getting getting an error:-

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filename'

I have followed the doc in the doc precisely but I still get these errors and I am not sure why.

My html form:-

```
<form action="/register", method="POST" ,enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" , name="image" , placeholder="Image">
</form>
```

my python flask code:-

```
#fetch user image
    userImage = request.files["image"]
    #upload userImage
    #create storageclient
    gcs = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("projectalpha24-e0c2991ff2c0.json")
    #get storage bucket
    bucket = gcs.get_bucket("projectalpha24.appspot.com")
    #create a blob and upload file content
    blob = bucket.blob(userImage.filename)

    blob.upload_from_string(
        userImage.read(),
        content_type=userImage.content_type
    )
```

I am not sure what's happening. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have edited the code. I have changed the way I fetching the image from the form to request.files["image"] and followed the documentation mentioned above 1 more time. Now i get a new error:-

The mimetype for the request is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "multipart/form-data" which means that no file contents were transmitted.  To fix this error you should provide enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form

Although, As you can see from my form code, I did include the enctype in my form, yet, it gives this error.

Comment: Is your error coming from this line? `userImage.filename(userImage.filename)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the file object by `userImage = request.files.get("image")`. Refer [this link](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-upload-file/) for more info.

Comment: I actually did you use this at some point of my trails but still didn't make much of a difference.